# React/Material UI - Handling open/close boxes in child components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So in my parent class, I currently have the following snippet code:

```
...
return (
      <div className={prefix}>
      {(toEditBooking===true ? <EditBooking editBooking={true} booking={selected}/> : null)}
      <Paper style={header} rounded={false}>
        <div className ={prefix+'-name'}>{name}</div>
        <div className ={prefix+'-flight'}>{refNo}</div>
        <div className ={prefix+'-initials'}>{initials}</div>
        <div className ...
```

As you can notice, I have a 'toEditBooking===true' which if the condition is met, loads a component called EditBooking and passes in a series of props.

In the child component called EditBooking, I have the following:

```
componentWillReceiveProps = () => {
  this.setState({open:this.props.editBooking})
}

state = {
  open: this.props.editBooking,
};

handleClose = () => {
  this.setState({open: false});
};
  render () {
    const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onClick={this.handleClose}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Submit"
        primary={true}
        keyboardFocused={true}
        onClick={this.handleClose}
      />,
    ];
    const booking = this.props.booking
    console.log(booking)
    return (

        <Dialog
          title="Edit Booking"
          autoDetectWindowHeight={false}
          autoScrollBodyContent={false}
          actions={actions}
          modal={false}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
        >
        <Paper className={prefix}>
        <Subheader>Please update the correct details below:</Subheader>
         <Subheader>Flight Details</Subheader>
         <Row middle="xs">
```

This works well for the first time, however, if the user closes the child component (EditBooking), I want the parent component to update its props to.

Is there an easy to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass another prop into your child component called onClose, this will be a callback that the child component will invoke when it closes.

```
<EditBooking editBooking={true} booking={selected} onClose={() => {
  // put all your logic to handle closing in the parent component
  // e.g. this.setState({ editBooking: false });
}} />
```

Then modify EditBooking.handleClose

```
handleClose = () => {
  this.setState({open: false});
  this.props.onClose(); // call callback provided by parent
};
```